# python - map muliple functions (in a iterable), single object

Tags: python

I am fairly new to python and yet to fully understand its concepts.
Orginally the code was something like this

```
def isSomething(s):
    result=False
    for f in listFunctions:
        if f(s):
            result=True
return result
```

So I was wondering if there is anything like this

```
def isSomething(s):
   return any(mapManyFunctions2Object(listFunctions,s))
```

where mapManyFunctions2Object() is just like but maps iterable list of Functions and a object.

Is there any standard function that could replace mapManyFunctions2Object() ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [any](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#any) with a [generator expression](http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#generator-expressions):

```
def isSomething(s):
   return any(f(s) for f in listFunctions))
```

One nice thing about using `any` with a generator expression is that `any` will short-circuit as soon as some `f(s)` returns a Truish value. So not all the functions in `listFunctions` will be called unless they all happen to return Falsish values.

Answer (score 1):

You can write such a function trivially:

```
def apply_all(functions, arg):
    return [function(arg) for function in functions]
```

Or, if you want a 3.x-style `map`-like:

```
def apply_all(functions, arg):
    yield from (function(arg) for function in functions)
```

However, you really don't need to, given that you can just use the expression itself just as easily.

`map` is worth having for historical reasons, familiarity from other languages, etc.—so long as the thing to be mapped is a nicely-named function, many people will instantly understand what `map(frotz, widgets)` means. I don't think that'll be true for `apply_all(frotzers, widget)`.

---

Just for fun, to define `apply_all` in terms of `map`:

```
def apply_all(functions, arg):
    return map(lambda function: function(arg), functions)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do this easily:

```
>>> listFunctions = [lambda x: x == 1, lambda x: x == 2, lambda x: x == 3]
>>> def isSomething(x):
...     return any(f(x) for f in listFunctions)
... 
>>> isSomething(3)   # run functions from list on 3, get results False, False and, finally, True
True
>>> isSomething(5)   # run functions from list on 5, all results is False
False
```